# Trouble with unidentified variables

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a hangman game and have gotten stumped with HTML, CSS and JS. I have the following which the bottom part gets triggered once a button is pushed the b in the function will determine which letter will be chosen from the array (ie 0,1 = alpha[1 - 1]) and the top is once there has been some sort of word input. I am having problems when I try and use the variables above to check if the letter chosen is in the input string. such as when I do console.log(store, input). it will come up as unidentified, I just need it so i can run letters through the string then check if the letter was in the word. I am a beginner so I hope it's not too much of a hassle, Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="hang.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="hang.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="push">
                <input type="string" placeholder="What is your word ?" id="input">
                <input type="button" onclick="word(1,0)" value=Submit>
            </div>
                <h2 class="output"></h2>
                    <div class="alpha">
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,1)">A</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,2)">B</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,3)">C</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,4)">D</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,5)">E</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,6)">F</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,7)">G</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,8)">H</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,9)">I</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,10)">J</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,11)">K</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,12)">L</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,13)">M</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,14)">N</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,15)">O</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,16)">P</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,17)">Q</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,18)">R</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,19)">S</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,20)">T</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,21)">U</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,22)">V</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,23)">W</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,24)">X</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,25)">Y</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,26)">Z</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,27)">_</h1>
                        <h1 onclick="word(0,28)">-</h1>
                    </div>
        </body>     
</html>
```

```js
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ', '-'];
// -------------------- changes and counts word into spaces

function word(a, b) {
    if (a === 1) {
        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        var store = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            store.push('_');
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].innerHTML = store;
        document.getElementById('input').value = '';
    } // -------------------------- checking if letter chosen is correct 
    else if (a === 0) {
        console.log(store, input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why word(a,b) when b is never used

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work? How exactly should the thing work? You can [edit] your question and extend the snippet to include the HTML as well as clarify your question.

Comment: Try array=string.split("") to get the word as an array

Comment: `store` and `input` are only assigned values to when `a === 1`, however they are used on the case where `a === 0`

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it plus I figured if I used a global variable it would be easier to use in another function that way it would also just be cleaner. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you get stuck somewhere ive wrote the complete script for you:

```
var secret="";
var letters=[];
var known=[];
function setsecret(a){
secret=a;
letters=secret.split("");
for(i=0;i<letters.length;i++){
known.push("_");
}
//display known
}
function check(letter){
for(i=0;i<letters.length;i++){
if(letters[i]==letter){
known[i]=letters[i];
}
}
if(letters==known){
alert("youve got it");
}
//display known
}
```

Secret stores our word, letters the word as array,known the guessed word. Use like this:

```
setsecret("ABRACADABRA");
check("A");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make variable "store" global, so it won't be empty next time you call word(). Also move the initialization of input outside the "if" block:

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', ...];
var store = [];

function word(){
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value; 
  if (a === 1) {
   ...
  }
}
```